# Why is og:image tag not showing any image on share?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have included image with dimension 600*315. The image appears correctly on all other similar posts but not on this one. I am attaching a screenshot of open graph properties inferred by Facebook Debugger

[image]

Comment: Facebook will crop images in all sorts of different ways.

Comment: This is currently the #1 bug on the homepage of Facebook's API bug tracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140/

Answer (score 1):

@Igy is right. This is a facebook problem and they are "actively working on this with a high priority

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140/